# how to implement ASP.NET Identity to an empty MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I create a new empty `MVC` project and I want to add identity to it.
Now I do not know how to do this and how to create database and tables and classes.
I searched but I did not find any useful solution for my question, I found an article for adding ASP.NET Identity to an existing empty ASP.NET Web from but for ASP.Net `MVC` project I did not find.
for log in
for registration form
for adding a user to role
for deleting user
how to create tables in my own database
how to manage users

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I was looking for the same thing and the following blog posts helped me with this:

http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-identity-stripped-bare-mvc-part-1

http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-identity-stripped-bare-mvc-part-2

Comment: Note: Newer Devs beware; The second link is out of date as of the release of Identity 2... [http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-identity-stripped-bare-mvc-part-2](http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-identity-stripped-bare-mvc-part-2) Save yourself the headache

Comment: How do you save yourself the headache? Sorry what are you recommending it's not clear?

Answer (score 9):

Open up the nuget package manager by going to:

```
Tools > Nuget Package Manager > Package Manager Console
```

in a new project<sup>[1]</sup>. From there, You can enter next to the `PM>`

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples -Pre
```

which will install the Identity sample for you. It will ask you if you allow it to alter your `webconfig` by pressing 'A' you accept all changes.

From then onwards, you'll have the sample identity project installed!

Note: It will change the default namespace, so by going to 'find and replace' you can quickly alter the occurrences to your project name (note, you may have to go into your `global.aspx` page in your my documents folder - open it in notepad and change the namespace there too!)

---

<sup>[1]</sup>: If you do not do this at the beginning of your development, you will find that the following files will be overwritten(so make sure you have a way to merge your originals with the new):

```
Overwrite existing file 'Views\Web.config'.
Overwrite existing file 'Views\Shared\Error.cshtml'.
Overwrite existing file 'Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml'.
Overwrite existing file 'Views\Home\Index.cshtml'.
Overwrite existing file 'Views\_ViewStart.cshtml'.
Overwrite existing file 'Global.asax.cs'.
Overwrite existing file 'Global.asax'.
Overwrite existing file 'Controllers\HomeController.cs'.
Overwrite existing file 'Content\Site.css'.
Overwrite existing file 'App_Start\RouteConfig.cs'.
Overwrite existing file 'App_Start\FilterConfig.cs'.
Overwrite existing file 'App_Start\BundleConfig.cs'.
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not find the package until I selected: Package source: All in the dropdown at the top of the window.

Comment: I did this and identity is working fine. Now how do i change localdb to mysql with identity samples?

Answer (score 1):

The following article explains you the basics of adding ASP.NET Identity to your application. http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/adding-aspnet-identity-to-an-empty-or-existing-web-forms-project

Comment: Raquel Almeida's paper is very good for webform app , but in this scenario we need tutorial to learn implement Identity in MVC app.
I watching your video on channel9 with title "ASP.NET Identity" and this video is very very good , but not good for newcomers in this case , i am a newcomers in this case , i need learn step by step , such as following links :
http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-identity-stripped-bare-mvc-part-1
http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-identity-stripped-bare-mvc-part-2

At end of thank you and your team , you did great work!

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate ASP.NET Identity from the NuGet gallery. You can install  these packages using the NuGet Package Manager Console, like this:

**Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework –Version 2.2.1**

**Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core -Version 2.2.1**

**Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.OWIN -Version 2.2.1**

Apart from that, you just create a separate MVC project with the default template and where you have classes and methods for implementation of ASP.NET identity as a reference so just use these classes in your new project as well.

If you are using existing database with Entity Framework with Database first approach then create the separate connection string and data context for ASP.NET identity.As Entity Framework with  Edmx uses the provider `System.Data.EntityClient` while ASP.NET Identity uses the provider `System.Data.SqlClient`.