# Add a page to Login System Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hi everyone i have a page asp.net but dont have any login system only a website project and 1 page. I prepared login system and registration system I want to add this project to login system MVC project But when i added to only page im giving a lot errors what's easy way to add this?

My website project :

[image]

My MVC project (with login system)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look into ASP.NET Identity [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22273362/how-to-implement-asp-net-identity-to-an-empty-mvc-project) is a good post on how to implement ASP.NET Identity to an empty MVC project.

These links help

http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-identity-stripped-bare-mvc-part-1

http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-identity-stripped-bare-mvc-part-2