# use old asp membership database for identity with mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

We have an old asp.net(web.forms) membership database(aspnet.users,membership,roles,etc..)
how can I integrate this with new mvc application.

I checked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22273362/how-to-implement-asp-net-identity-to-an-empty-mvc-project) but this uses a completely new database, and according to this [post](http://Can%20I%20import%20an%20existing%20member%20data%20used%20in%20old%20ASP%20to%20a%20new%20ASP.NET%20membership%20database?) , it's gonna be a pain. I'm wondering whether this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31960433/adding-asp-net-mvc5-identity-authentication-to-an-existing-project) would work. I will of course hook up our custom user identity. I just need the core or main steps to do this.

Thanks..

[image: I have to use that]

Comment: If you have the stored procs that go with the tables, it's not like you can't just call those instead of using the built in tools that were found in the older versions of .net.

Comment: unfortunately they are using  the built in asp.net tools for authentication..it is just extended for other membership properties

Comment: What I was saying is that with the stored procs which come with the membrership database you have the same capability as the you would with the build in tools. Additionally, if you're moving them into something new, you probably won't be bringing in those asp.net webform controls, you'll be wanting to use something different.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45873006/how-to-consume-and-asp-net-membership-database-in-asp-net-identity).  It demonstrates how to implement IUserStore, IUserPasswordStore, IUserEmailStore and IPasswordHasher to consume an exising ASP.NET Membership database in ASP.NET Identity.