# How to consume and ASP.NET Membership database in ASP.NET Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, passwords, asp.net-membership, identityserver4

I have a couple of legacy ASP.NET web apps that share a database for ASP.NET Membership.  I want to move to a microservices architecture utilizing .NET Core and IdentityServer4 and have the identity server in the new microservices ecosystem to use the existing ASP.NET Membership user store, but .NET Core doesn't appear to support ASP.NET Membership at all.

I currently have a proof of concept stood up involving a web API, identity server and an MVC web app as my client.  The identity server implements a subclass of IdentityUser and implements IUserStore/IUserPasswordStore/IUserEmailStore to adapt it to the ASP.NET Membership tables in my existing database.  I can register new users and login via my POC MVC client app but these users cannot log into my legacy apps.  Conversely, users registered in legacy apps can't log into my POC MVC client.  I assume its because my implementation of IPasswordHasher isn't hashing the passwords the same as ASP.NET Membership in my legacy apps.

Below is my code.  Any insight into what I might be doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.  Security and cryptography are not my strong suit.

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            // For more details on using the user secret store see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532709
            builder.AddUserSecrets<Startup>();
        }

        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        /* Add CORS policy */
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            // this defines a CORS policy called "default"
            options.AddPolicy("default", policy =>
            {
                policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5003")
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod();
            });
        });
        services.AddMvcCore()
            .AddAuthorization()
            .AddJsonFormatters();

        /* Add MVC componenets. */
        services.AddMvc();

        /* Configure IdentityServer. */
        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            // Password settings
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;

            // Lockout settings
            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 10;

            // Cookie settings
            options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(150);
            options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
            options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout";

            // User settings
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        });

        /* Add the DbContext */
        services.AddDbContext<StoreContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString")));

        /* Add ASP.NET Identity to use for registration and authentication. */
        services.AddIdentity<AspNetMembershipUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<StoreContext>()
            .AddUserStore<AspNetMembershipUserStore>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddTransient<IPasswordHasher<AspNetMembershipUser>, AspNetMembershipPasswordHasher>();

        /* Add IdentityServer and its components. */
        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddInMemoryCaching()
            .AddTemporarySigningCredential()
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients());
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        /* Configure logging. */
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        /* Configure wwwroot */
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        /* Configure CORS */
        app.UseCors("default");

        /* Configure AspNet Identity */
        app.UseIdentity();

        /* Configure IdentityServer */
        app.UseIdentityServer();

        /* Configure MVC */
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

**AspNetMembershipUser.cs**

```
public class AspNetMembershipUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }
    public int PasswordFormat { get; set; }
}
```

**AspNetMembershipUserStore.cs**

```
public class AspNetMembershipUserStore : IUserStore<AspNetMembershipUser>, IUserPasswordStore<AspNetMembershipUser>, IUserEmailStore<AspNetMembershipUser>
{
    private readonly StoreContext _dbcontext;

    public AspNetMembershipUserStore(StoreContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbcontext = dbContext;
    }

    public Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(AspNetMembershipUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                User dbUser = new User();
                this.Convert(user, dbUser);
                _dbcontext.Users.Add(dbUser);
                _dbcontext.SaveChanges();
                return IdentityResult.Success;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return IdentityResult.Failed(new IdentityError
                {
                    Code = ex.GetType().Name,
                    Description = ex.Message
                });
            }
        });
    }

    public Task<IdentityResult> DeleteAsync(AspNetMembershipUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                User dbUser = _dbcontext.Users
                    .Include(u => u.AspNetUsers).ThenInclude(u => u.AspNetMembership)
                    .Include(u => u.AspNetUsers).ThenInclude(u => u.AspNetApplication)
                    .Include(u => u.UserGroups)
                    .SingleOrDefault(u => u.ProviderUserName == user.NormalizedUserName);

                if (dbUser != null)
                {
                    _dbcontext.AspNetUsers.Remove(dbUser.AspNetUser);
                    _dbcontext.Users.Remove(dbUser);
                    _dbcontext.SaveChanges();
                }

                return IdentityResult.Success;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return IdentityResult.Failed(new IdentityError
                {
                    Code = ex.GetType().Name,
                    Description = ex.Message
                });
            }
        });
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _dbcontext.Dispose();
    }

    public Task<AspNetMembershipUser> FindByEmailAsync(string normalizedEmail, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            User dbUser = _dbcontext.Users
                .Include(u => u.AspNetUsers).ThenInclude(u => u.AspNetMembership)
                .Include(u => u.AspNetUsers).ThenInclude(u => u.AspNetApplication)
                .Include(u => u.UserGroups)
                .SingleOrDefault(u => u.ProviderEmailAddress == normalizedEmail);

            if (dbUser == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            AspNetMembershipUser user = new AspNetMembershipUser();
            this.Convert(dbUser, user);
            return user;
        });
    }

    public Task<AspNetMembershipUser> FindByIdAsync(string userId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        long lUserId = long.Parse(userId);
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            User dbUser = _dbcontext.Users
                .Include(u => u.AspNetUsers).ThenInclude(u => u.AspNetMembership)
                .Include(u => u.AspNetUsers).ThenInclude(u=> u.AspNetApplication)
                .Include(u => u.UserGroups)
                .SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserId == lUserId);

            if (dbUser == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            AspNetMembershipUser user = new AspNetMembershipUser();
            this.Convert(dbUser, user);
            return user;
        });
    }

    public Task<AspNetMembershipUser> FindByNameAsync(string normalizedUserName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            User dbUser = _dbcontext.Users
                .Include(u => u.AspNetUsers).ThenInclude(u => u.AspNetMembership)
                .Include(u => u.AspNetUsers).ThenInclude(u => u.AspNetApplication)
                .Include(u => u.UserGroups)
                .SingleOrDefault(u => u.ProviderUserName == normalizedUserName);

            if (dbUser == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            AspNetMembershipUser user = new AspNetMembershipUser();
            this.Convert(dbUser, user);
            return user;
        });
    }

    public Task<string> GetEmailAsync(AspNetMembershipUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => user.Email);
    }

    public Task<bool> GetEmailConfirmedAsync(AspNetMembershipUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => user.EmailConfirmed);
    }

    public Task<string> GetNormalizedEmailAsync(AspNetMembershipUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => user.NormalizedEmail);
    }

    public Task<string> GetNormalizedUserNameAsync(AspNetMembershipUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => user.NormalizedUserName);
    }

    public Task<string> GetPasswordHashAsync(AspNetMembershipUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => user.PasswordHash);
    }

    public Task<string> GetUserIdAsync(AspNetMembershipUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => user.Id.ToString());
    }

    public Task<string> GetUserNameAsync(AspNetMembershipUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => user.UserName);
    }

    public Task<bool> HasPasswordAsync(AspNetMembershipUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.PasswordHash));
    }

    public Task SetEmailAsync(AspNetMembershipUser user, string email, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => user.Email = email);
    }

    public Task SetEmailConfirmedAsync(AspNetMembershipUser user, bool confirmed, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => user.EmailConfirmed = confirmed);
    }

    public Task SetNormalizedEmailAsync(AspNetMembershipUser user, string normalizedEmail, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => user.NormalizedEmail = normalizedEmail);
    }

    public Task SetNormalizedUserNameAsync(AspNetMembershipUser user, string normalizedName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => user.NormalizedUserName = normalizedName);
    }

    public Task SetPasswordHashAsync(AspNetMembershipUser user, string passwordHash, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => user.PasswordHash = passwordHash);
    }

    public Task SetUserNameAsync(AspNetMembershipUser user, string userName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => user.UserName = userName);
    }

    public Task<IdentityResult> UpdateAsync(AspNetMembershipUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                User dbUser = _dbcontext.Users
                    .Include(u => u.AspNetUsers).ThenInclude(u => u.AspNetMembership)
                    .Include(u => u.AspNetUsers).ThenInclude(u => u.AspNetApplication)
                    .Include(u => u.UserGroups)
                    .SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserId.ToString() == user.Id);

                if (dbUser != null)
                {
                    this.Convert(user, dbUser);
                    _dbcontext.Users.Update(dbUser);
                    _dbcontext.SaveChanges();
                }
                return IdentityResult.Success;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return IdentityResult.Failed(new IdentityError
                {
                    Code = ex.GetType().Name,
                    Description = ex.Message
                });
            }
        });
    }

    private void Convert(User from, AspNetMembershipUser to)
    {
        to.Id = from.ProviderUserKey.ToString();
        to.UserName = from.ProviderUserName;
        to.NormalizedUserName = from.ProviderUserName.ToLower();
        to.Email = from.ProviderEmailAddress;
        to.NormalizedEmail = from.ProviderEmailAddress.ToLower();
        to.EmailConfirmed = true;
        to.PasswordHash = from.AspNetUser.AspNetMembership.Password;
        to.PasswordSalt = from.AspNetUser.AspNetMembership.PasswordSalt;
        to.PasswordFormat = from.AspNetUser.AspNetMembership.PasswordFormat;
        to.AccessFailedCount = from.AspNetUser.AspNetMembership.FailedPasswordAttemptCount;
        to.EmailConfirmed = true;
        to.Roles.Clear();
        from.UserGroups.ToList().ForEach(ug =>
        {
            to.Roles.Add(new IdentityUserRole<string>
            {
                RoleId = ug.GroupId.ToString(),
                UserId = ug.UserId.ToString()
            });
        });
        to.PhoneNumber = from.Phone ?? from.ShippingPhone;
        to.PhoneNumberConfirmed = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(to.PhoneNumber);
        to.SecurityStamp = from.AspNetUser.AspNetMembership.PasswordSalt;
    }

    private void Convert(AspNetMembershipUser from , User to)
    {
        AspNetApplication application = _dbcontext.AspNetApplications.First();

        to.ProviderUserKey = Guid.Parse(from.Id);
        to.ProviderUserName = from.UserName;
        to.ProviderEmailAddress = from.Email;
        to.InternalEmail = $"c_{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}@mycompany.com";
        to.AccountOwner = "MYCOMPANY";
        to.UserStatusId = (int)UserStatus.Normal;

        AspNetUser aspNetUser = to.AspNetUser;

        if (to.AspNetUser == null)
        {
            to.AspNetUser = new AspNetUser
            {
                ApplicationId = application.ApplicationId,
                AspNetApplication= application,
                AspNetMembership = new AspNetMembership
                {
                    ApplicationId = application.ApplicationId,
                    AspNetApplication = application
                }
            };
        }

        to.AspNetUser.UserId = Guid.Parse(from.Id);
        to.AspNetUser.UserName = from.UserName;
        to.AspNetUser.LoweredUserName = from.UserName.ToLower();
        to.AspNetUser.LastActivityDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        to.AspNetUser.IsAnonymous = false;
        to.AspNetUser.ApplicationId = application.ApplicationId;
        to.AspNetUser.AspNetMembership.CreateDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        to.AspNetUser.AspNetMembership.Email = from.Email;
        to.AspNetUser.AspNetMembership.IsApproved = true;
        to.AspNetUser.AspNetMembership.LastLoginDate = DateTime.Parse("1754-01-01 00:00:00.000");
        to.AspNetUser.AspNetMembership.LastLockoutDate = DateTime.Parse("1754-01-01 00:00:00.000");
        to.AspNetUser.AspNetMembership.LastPasswordChangedDate = DateTime.Parse("1754-01-01 00:00:00.000");
        to.AspNetUser.AspNetMembership.LoweredEmail = from.NormalizedEmail.ToLower();
        to.AspNetUser.AspNetMembership.Password = from.PasswordHash;
        to.AspNetUser.AspNetMembership.PasswordSalt = from.PasswordSalt;
        to.AspNetUser.AspNetMembership.PasswordFormat = from.PasswordFormat;
        to.AspNetUser.AspNetMembership.IsLockedOut = false;
        to.AspNetUser.AspNetMembership.FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart = DateTime.Parse("1754-01-01 00:00:00.000");
        to.AspNetUser.AspNetMembership.FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart = DateTime.Parse("1754-01-01 00:00:00.000");

        // Merge Groups/Roles
        to.UserGroups
            .Where(ug => !from.Roles.Any(r => ug.GroupId.ToString() == r.RoleId))
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(ug => to.UserGroups.Remove(ug));

        to.UserGroups
            .Join(from.Roles, ug => ug.GroupId.ToString(), r => r.RoleId, (ug, r) => new { To = ug, From = r })
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(j =>
            {
                j.To.UserId = long.Parse(j.From.UserId);
                j.To.GroupId = int.Parse(j.From.RoleId);
            });

        from.Roles
            .Where(r => !to.UserGroups.Any(ug => ug.GroupId.ToString() == r.RoleId))
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(r =>
            {
                to.UserGroups.Add(new UserGroup
                {
                    UserId = long.Parse(from.Id),
                    GroupId = int.Parse(r.RoleId)
                });
            });
    }
}
```

**AspNetMembershipPasswordHasher.cs**

```
public class AspNetMembershipPasswordHasher : IPasswordHasher<AspNetMembershipUser>
{
    private readonly int _saltSize;
    private readonly int _bytesRequired;
    private readonly int _iterations;

    public AspNetMembershipPasswordHasher()
    {
        this._saltSize = 128 / 8;
        this._bytesRequired = 32;
        this._iterations = 1000;
    }

    public string HashPassword(AspNetMembershipUser user, string password)
    {
        string passwordHash = null;
        string passwordSalt = null;

        this.HashPassword(password, out passwordHash, ref passwordSalt);

        user.PasswordSalt = passwordSalt;
        return passwordHash;
    }

    public PasswordVerificationResult VerifyHashedPassword(AspNetMembershipUser user, string hashedPassword, string providedPassword)
    {
        // Throw an error if any of our passwords are null
        if (hashedPassword == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("hashedPassword");
        }

        if (providedPassword == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("providedPassword");
        }

        string providedPasswordHash = null;

        if (user.PasswordFormat == 0)
        {
            providedPasswordHash = providedPassword;
        }
        else if (user.PasswordFormat == 1)
        {

            string providedPasswordSalt = user.PasswordSalt;

            this.HashPassword(providedPassword, out providedPasswordHash, ref providedPasswordSalt);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("Encrypted passwords are not supported.");
        }

        if (providedPasswordHash == hashedPassword)
        {
            return PasswordVerificationResult.Success;
        }
        else
        {
            return PasswordVerificationResult.Failed;
        }
    }

    private void HashPassword(string password, out string passwordHash, ref string passwordSalt)
    {
        byte[] hashBytes = null;
        byte[] saltBytes = null;
        byte[] totalBytes = new byte[this._saltSize + this._bytesRequired];

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(passwordSalt))
        {
            // Using existing salt.
            using (var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, Convert.FromBase64String(passwordSalt), this._iterations))
            {
                saltBytes = pbkdf2.Salt;
                hashBytes = pbkdf2.GetBytes(this._bytesRequired);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Generate a new salt.
            using (var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, this._saltSize, this._iterations))
            {
                saltBytes = pbkdf2.Salt;
                hashBytes = pbkdf2.GetBytes(this._bytesRequired);
            }
        }

        Buffer.BlockCopy(saltBytes, 0, totalBytes, 0, this._saltSize);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(hashBytes, 0, totalBytes, this._saltSize, this._bytesRequired);

        using (SHA256 hashAlgorithm = SHA256.Create())
        {
            passwordHash = Convert.ToBase64String(hashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(totalBytes));
            passwordSalt = Convert.ToBase64String(saltBytes);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of my coworkers was able to help me out.  Below is what the hash function should look like.  With this change, ASP.NET Identity is able to piggy back on an existing ASP.NET Membership database.

```
private void HashPassword(string password, out string passwordHash, ref string passwordSalt)
    {
        byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password);
        byte[] saltBytes = null;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(passwordSalt))
        {
            saltBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(passwordSalt);
        }
        else
        {
            saltBytes = new byte[128 / 8];
            using (var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
            {
                rng.GetBytes(saltBytes);
            }
        }

        byte[] totalBytes = new byte[saltBytes.Length + passwordBytes.Length];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(saltBytes, 0, totalBytes, 0, saltBytes.Length);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(passwordBytes, 0, totalBytes, saltBytes.Length, passwordBytes.Length);

        using (SHA1 hashAlgorithm = SHA1.Create())
        {
            passwordHash = Convert.ToBase64String(hashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(totalBytes));
        }

        passwordSalt = Convert.ToBase64String(saltBytes);
    }
```

You can find all the [source code on GitHib](https://github.com/yarsiemanym/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.AspNetMembershipAdapter).