# Can ASP.NET Identity cookies be backwards compatible with Forms Authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, asp.net-identity, forms-authentication

I have a number of existing ASP.NET MVC web application that all use ASP.NET Membership and Forms Authentication and *not* using OWIN, but I would like new apps to be developed in .NET Core 1.1 using IdentityServer4 for auth.  I have an IdentityServer implemented with a custom user store so existing users from the old ASP.NET Membership database can log into my IdentityServer (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45873006/how-to-consume-and-asp-net-membership-database-in-asp-net-identity) StackOverflow question for more information about that), however the authentication cookie created by ASP.NET Identity isn't recognized by the older apps using Forms Authentication.

I'd like to have single sign-on between the older Forms Authentication apps and the newer apps using ASP.NET Identity, preferably with make as few changes as possible to the older apps.  Is there a way to make ASP.NET Identity generate authentication cookies that Forms Authentication can understand?

I think in both cases, the contents of the cookie is a serialized and encrypted `ClaimsPrincipal` so it seems like my big stumbling block is getting both the Forms Authentication app and the ASP.NET Identity app to be on the same page with respect to encrypting/decrypting the cookie.  Since Forms Authentication encrypts the cookie using the `<machineKey>` element in the web.config file and ASP.NET Identity in .NET Core uses DPAPI, I'll have to figure out how to bridge that gap.  Maybe something like this?

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
    {
        ...

        options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.DataProtectionProvider = 
            new FormsAuthenticationDataProtector();

        ...
    });
}
```

**FormsAuthenticationDataProtector.cs**

```
public class FormsAuthenticationDataProtector : IDataProtector
{
    public IDataProtector CreateProtector(string purpose)
    {
        return this;
    }

    public byte[] Protect(byte[] plaintext)
    {
        // TODO: Mimic the Forms Authentication encryption algorithm.
    }

    public byte[] Unprotect(byte[] protectedData)
    {
        // TODO: Mimic the Forms Authentication decryption algorithm.
    }
}
```

But I have no idea what the bodies of the `Protect()` and `Unprotect()` methods should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This discussion](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1405) I had with a couple of ASP.NET Identity and IdentityServer devs on GitHub was really helpful.  The short answer to my question about sharing a cookie between Forms Authentication and ASP.NET Identity was "You're insane!"  Fortunately, there are some alternatives.

Brock Allen pointed me to [IdentityServer's GitHub repo for client examples](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples).  For me, I think the [MvcFormPostClient example](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Clients/MvcFormPostClient) is going to do the trick.  It's actually not that hard to implement OpenID Connect in an older MVC app without OWIN or ASP.NET Identity.