# ASP.net Identity Tutorial

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, identity

I was looking for a good tutorial that goes step by step to show how to implement the .net identity into the mvc framework and was unable to find any good tutorials, so could someone recommend me a good tutorial that will help me get started with identity?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are a few tutorials on Identity:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-deploy-aspnet-mvc-app-membership-oauth-sql-database

[how to implement ASP.NET Identity to an empty MVC project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22273362/how-to-implement-asp-net-identity-to-an-empty-mvc-project)

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/762428/ASP-NET-MVC-and-Identity-Understanding-the-Basics

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/securing-asp.net-mvc-applications-with-asp.net-identity.htm

Answer (score 2):

Here you go mate, hope it helps out:
https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/microsoft-net/configuring-asp-net-identity

http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-identity-stripped-bare-mvc-part-1

http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-identity-stripped-bare-mvc-part-2